# Virtualization seems to be messing up binded properties

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, dependency-properties, virtualization

I've got a listview that has, as a datatemplate, a relatively complex UserControl, with a couple properties that are being binded to it.

The ItemsPanel is the following:

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <ItemsStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

My listview generally contains about 70 items, however I'm running into quite a major issue:

Every time I scroll up about 30 items and then go back down, the properties seem to have gotten messed up, and some of them seem to have switched with the properties of items higher up.

For example, if before I had the following:

- property A = 1
- property A = 2
- property A = 3

After scrolling up and back down I would have:

- property A = 1
- property A = 2
- property A = 1

How can I ensure that the items either keep their properties or reload them correctly?

Comment: What's the result if you prevent the virtualization?Did you have a [mcve] project for testing on our side?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this issue. As @SunteenWu-MSFT said - you should provide an MCVE (you're likely to pinpoint the problem while at it).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to fix this: If anyone else is running into a similar issue, it's potentially because you're handling the PropertyChanged event without resetting properties that are missing or are null. For example, if this is the usercontrol inside the datatemplate of a listview:

`<local:CustomControl CustomText={Binding text}/>`

And it is being handled like this:

```
    public string CustomText        
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CustomTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CustomTextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(CustomText),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(CustomControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var instance = d as CustomControl;
        if(instance.CustomText != "") 
            myTextBlock.Text = instance.CustomText;
    }
```

Every time that virtualization recycles a CustomControl, if ever it is being binded to an empty string, because of the `if(instance.CustomText != "")` the textblock will not get updated, and old properties will show up again. The same will happen if OnPropertyChanged never gets called for some reason.

It seems kind of stupid in this particular situation, but it can get quite confusing on large usercontrols with a lot of properties and subproperties